# use jquery to animate lines of text

Tags: jquery

I have a paragragh of text.

```
<p>
line1
line2
line3
</p>
```

intially all the text are red
when a button is pressed
each line's color changes to black gradually (2 sec each line)

can this be done with only jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be done with jQuery but you will need the Color Animation plugin...

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

EDIT: Sorry mate this script should do it for you (you will need the color plugin still)

```
// Rename #go to the trigger that starts the animation
$("#go").click(function () {
    var i = -1;
    // Rename #container to the name of the element surrounding the p tags
    var arr = $("#container p");
    (function () {
        if (arr[++i])
            $(arr[i]).animate({ color: "#ff0000" }, 2000, "linear", arguments.callee)
    })();
});
```

Comment: it changes all lines at the same time. how can i change the color one line at a time?